# How to show a significant difference between two prediction populations obtained by different ML methods?

Tags: machine-learning

My goal is to compare two diferent ML methods for a prediction problem. I ve run both methods on a simulated data set with a known true value a 1000 times and obtained a prediction distribution as in the plot below.
[image]

further I computed some empirical moments as in the figure below[image]

I havent calculated the CI, because i was not sure about the type of the resulting distribution and decided to go with the quantiles, so i can just say, that 95% of all of the predictions obtained by method 2 are located in a tighter bound than those obtained by the method 1.

Is the above sufficient to state, that the Method 2 offers a significantly better performance on the simulated dataset than the method 1 ?
Or should i run a t-test or some MWW, if yes, what exactly would you suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

Going to the higher quantile in this specific question is some sort of p-hacking. You look at test results where the difference is greater, in hope, that your results or ML methods shall 'look' more different/significant to the reader in terms of accuracy or whatsoever. That is not debatable or in other words: I wouldnt do it. So judging your methods by this is not possible.

Although the bond might be tighter by a visual, you can and should test this with a t-test, if you are interested in this. Yet, I would advise you to look at this link https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat200/lesson/6/6.4
It tells you something about effect size or practical significance, and even without knowing your ML methods or your target outcome, I would sadly say to you, that these results have no practical significance, even if a test might indicate a statistical significance.

Yet, it depends on your research field. If variance shows i dunno the bouncing of an atom or neuron to predict its possible ranges and the first ML method can catch it better in terms of nano or peta units as a higher variance means a possible collide, then yeah, maybe we had a practical significance. But at the moment, I would say these methods are not so different. Especially, because the distributions have the same shape, and are both around your true mean. But as i said, it also depends on your research field.

However, if you are interested into the different densities that your ML methods create in term of distributions, then the Kolmogorov-Smirnoff-test might be a better idea:

https://eranraviv.com/test-of-equality-between-two-densities/